# How to scope Tailwind Css

Tags: tailwind-css

I cannot find a good way to scope tailwind CSS when including it in a system where I don't want it to apply globally that works with custom build options.

Essentially I want to do this:

```
.tailwind{
    @import "tailwindcss/base";

    @import "tailwindcss/components";

    @import "tailwindcss/utilities";
}
```

But PostCSS importer doesn't like this due to the fact it imports before the tailwind placeholders are replaced.  So the only way to make it work is to break the build into 2 stages then import the compiled css like:

```
.tailwind{
    @import "tailwindcss.css";
}
```

It works but it breaks some of the css rules which show up in dev tools.

Is there a better way to scope tailwind to stop it interfering with other systems?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[From the docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#prefix)...

> The prefix option allows you to add a custom prefix to all of Tailwind's generated utility classes. This can be really useful when layering Tailwind on top of existing CSS where there might be naming conflicts.
>
> For example, you could add a tw- prefix by setting the prefix option like so:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  prefix: 'tw-',
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work.  All the resets and default title values etc.. which cause conflicts are not prefixed

Comment: I mean, how would you make them work? For example `input { margin: 0 }`. If you have prefix class like `.tw input { margin: 0 }` then it's still all or nothing approach, if you add it then all default values will apply to everything anyway, if you don't then nothing will work.

Comment: I want to apply the class to the pages/sections that will have tailwind html.  Applying tailwind css globally to the existing system causes a lot of layouts to break so it needs to be scoped.  A prefix class like you showed fixes the specific problem that I have.  The prefix functionality in tailwind doesn't work like this though, it just prefixes classes.

Comment: Is it just the preflight that's breaking for you (the reset on things like input, etc?) Maybe just go here https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/2b0b306a77cc0f34cd25054a0d661a18278786bc/src/plugins/css/preflight.css

Comment: ...and copy-paste the preflight and drop in into your CSS instead of using the @import "tailwind/base"? It's only 200 lines of not-that-interesting CSS. I get that this is brittle but it's not likely to be an area of active development

Comment: using a custom base is best solution and works well

Comment: @Guerrilla could you add an answer with your solution? I am unable to generate a custom base.

Comment: @adelriosantiago added

Answer (score 19):

I've found that you can use [postcss-nested](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-nested) for this. Install the plugin, add it as the first plugin to your PostCSS config file and this should work:

```
.tailwind {
    @tailwind base;
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;
    @tailwind screens;
}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me in a small Vue 3 app that was being inserted into a larger website. Simply added `import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css'` into my `main.js` Changed the `postcss.config.js` to include the `postcss-nested` plugin. Added `<style lang="scss">#app {@tailwind base;  @tailwind components; @tailwind utilities; @tailwind screens;}</style>` into my root `App.vue`

Comment: Sadly, this no longer works. Tailwind has a specific file to detect nesting and spit out: "Nested @tailwind rules were detected, but are not supported.
Consider using a prefix to scope Tailwind's classes"

Answer (score 8):

You will achieve this by setting `important` in the tailwind config to your parent class or id. See [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#selector-strategy).

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  important: '.tailwind',
}
```

Unfortunately, this seems to only be affecting the *components* and *utilities* styles... the *base* styles will remain unaffected.

Comment: Do you mean `important: true` ?  That will add important to all properties but it doesn't help at all with scoping tailwind.  It will make situation worse.

Comment: No, `important: true` will only add `!important` to all styles. Though, setting the `important` value to a string will add a scope. For example, `important: '.tailwind'` will transform utilities like `.p-10 { ... }` to `.tailwind .p-10 { ... }`.

Comment: 100% right good knowledge shared thanks bro @CyrusKorn

Answer (score 8):

I think the tricky part here is actually about the preflight/reset.css. You want to fend off external styling from coming to your scope but also don't want to pollute the external system with your tailwind style.

My current set up include following steps:

1. In **tailwind.config.js** we disable the prefight, defining a prefix `tw-`, and adding an extra selector `#app` via option **important**. The last change will add an extra css selector to output, e.g. `#app .tw-mb-4`.

```js
module.exports = {
  important: '#app',
  prefix: "tw-",
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  },
```

2. Find and copy the content of `base.css` from node_modules folder before pasting it into a scss file with a parent selector `#app`. You can compile this using any online SCSS compiler. This will help you only reset styling within your scope.

```
#app {
  /*content from base.css*/
}
```

3. Copy compiled the styling from #2 and paste to the **beginning** of your tailwind css file.
4. Structure the html so you contents are wrapped within a div with the id of `#app`.
5. Tailwind's `important` option doesn't seem to add selector to `@layer component` so you will have to include that in your component styling.

```css
@layer components {
    #app .page-h1 {
        @apply tw-mt-0 tw-mb-2 tw-text-center tw-leading-8 tw-text-4xl md:tw-text-5xl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As requested leaving my answer here:

I used the prefix as suggested by Lanny

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  prefix: 'tw-',
}
```

And then made my tailwind css file like this:

```
    @import "tailwindcss/components";

    @import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

Then I just manually copied any base styles that I wanted manually into my main css file and manually changed anything that conflicted.

Comment: The latter worked great for me -- tailwind layout shorthands are great, but I don't always want to override the base tags!

Comment: Out of all of these solutions, this one also worked for me. The key is that tailwind base styles some global components so taking that out fixes the problem i was running into

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#disabling-preflight):

> If you’d like to completely disable Preflight — perhaps because you’re integrating Tailwind into an existing project or because you’d like to provide your own base styles — all you need to do is set preflight to false in the corePlugins section of your tailwind.config.js file.

This seems to work with Wordpress in the admin but it *does* remove the normalization, like cursor: pointer on button hover, for example.

Answer (score 3):

I have created a `vite` plugin to solve this problem.

- Very easy to use
- non-invasive
- minimal code changes

```
import scopeTailwind from "vite-plugin-scope-tailwind";

export default defineConfig({
    ...
    plugins: [
        ...
        scopeTailwind(), // or scopeTailwind({ react: true }) for a React app
        ...
    ],
    ...
});
```

### GitHub:

https://github.com/dolanmiu/vite-plugin-scope-tailwind

### npm:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-scope-tailwind

Answer (score 1):

What I have done is this

```
module.exports = {
      prefix: 'tw-',
      content: [
        "./src/**/*.{html,ts}",
      ],
      theme: {
        extend: {},
      },
      purge: {
        enabled: true,
        content: ['./src/**/*.{html,ts}']
      },
      plugins: [],
      corePlugins: {
        preflight: false,
      }
    }
```

It will reduce build size as ,I have purged CSS, disable global CSS,as I have used preflight, and now If u want to apply tailwind class use as

```
<div class="tw-m-4"></div>
```

As we have used tw in prefix

Answer (score 1):

[@jacob_frankovic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77359691/1349459)'s answer worked great for me, all styles are scoped now, thanks! But this way you'll have that **`compileString` from `sass` included in your build** which's definitely not what you want to get. At least because it adds a huge piece of code (i had >3mb added).

As a quick improvement the suggested logic could be placed into `vite.config.(ts|js)` file in a form of a plugin:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
// ...other imports
import { compileString } from "sass";

export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  plugins: [
    (() => {
      return {
        name: "ScopedTailwindStyles",
        transform(src, id) {
          // check if we're dealing with an scss file and do nothing if not
          if (!id.includes(".scss")) return;
                    
          // return an updated file source string 
          return { code: compileString(`.YOUR-SCOPE-SELECTOR { ${src} }`).css, map: null };
        },
      };
    })(),
  ],
  // ...
})
```

Of course a much more neater approach would be to put this code into a separate plugin file as [official docs recommend](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#simple-examples):

```js
// vite-plugin-scoped-styles.js

import { compileString } from "sass";

export default function scopedStyles() {
  return {
    name: "ScopedTailwindStyles",
    transform(src, id) {
      if (!id.includes(".scss")) return;
      return { code: compileString(`.YOUR-SCOPE-SELECTOR { ${src} }`).css, map: null };
    },
  };
}
```

and then include it into config:

```js
// vite.config.(ts|js)

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
// ...other imports
import scopedStyles from "./vite-plugin-scoped-styles.js";

export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  plugins: [scopedStyles()]
  // ...
})
```

You can also add some config for the plugin, eg., check for specific file names/extensions, set scope selector etc.

Answer (score 0):

### 2023 custom workaround using Javascript / Typescript

*Attention: This answer is for people who really need to scope tailwind by a CSS selector and cannot use prefix or important feature of tailwind config. Also this answer covers scenario when you use Javascript to import CSS to your app.*

Based on fact that vite / tailwind blocked support for [@Luud Janssen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67383170/13935477) approach, logging next text during build:

```
Nested @tailwind rules were detected, but are not supported. Consider using a prefix to scope Tailwind's classes...
```

I came out with next idea after spending hours to figure it out using postcss without success. I do not change anything in postcss config file, or vite config file.

My project is build in Vue3 + Vite, so basically I was importing the root tailwind.css file inside entry TS file (typically main.ts). The dependency needed to be installed is **sass**.

#### Steps

##### 1.

Please, remove this import and go to root component of your app (typically App.vue) and import tailwind file and compileString function from **sass** lib:

```
import tailwindFile from '@/core/assets/tailwind/tailwind.css?inline';
import { compileString } from 'sass';
```

*Vue recommends using ?inline when importing static css files inside components.*

##### 2.

After that, also inside setup script of component, execute:

```
const tailwindScoped = compileString(`.scope { ${tw} }`).css;
```

Now, in **tailwindScoped** variable, there is a string with scoped tailwind classes, with purging and custom classes working.

##### 3.

Finally, I use it in template in style HTML tag. By the way, the tag is forbidden to use by Vue, so there is also a workaround
to do that:

```
<component :is="'style'">
  {{ tailwindScoped }}
</component>
```

I know this isn't the best approach and also costs performance, but I couldn't find out any other method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method that worked for me. After using a prefix and removing Preflight, I still got leakage. So instead I used [CSS layers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@layer) to scope the CSS:

```
@layer myapp;
@layer myapp {
  @tailwind base;
  @tailwind components;
  @tailwind utilities;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a plugin that does the job pretty well (according to installations and feedback that I receive):

It locks the tailwind preflight styles within the specified CSS selector. Or vice versa ('except matched' mode) when only specified root is protected from the preflight styles.

#### V2 (stable)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailwindcss-scoped-preflight

```bash
npm i tailwindcss-scoped-preflight
```

Straightforward and good to go:

```js
// # tailwind.config.js

const { scopedPreflightStyles } = require('tailwindcss-scoped-preflight');

/** @type {import("tailwindcss").Config} */
const config = {
    // ... your Tailwind CSS config
    plugins: [
        // ... other plugins
        scopedPreflightStyles({
            cssSelector: '.twp', // or .tailwind-preflight or even [data-twp=true] - any valid CSS selector of your choice
            mode: 'matched only', // it's the default, another mode is 'except matched'
        }),
    ],
};

exports.default = config;
```

#### V3 (beta)

Just released (as a [beta release](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailwindcss-scoped-preflight/?activeTab=versions) yet) - provides a lot of flexibility (optionally) for some complex and hardcore cases.

```bash
npm i tailwindcss-scoped-preflight@next
```

```js
// # tailwind.config.js

import {
  scopedPreflightStyles,
  isolateForComponents, // there are also isolateInsideOfContainer and isolateOutsideOfContainer
} from 'tailwindcss-scoped-preflight';

/** @type {import("tailwindcss").Config} */
const config = {
  // ... your Tailwind CSS config
  plugins: [
    // ... other plugins
    scopedPreflightStyles({
      isolationStrategy: isolateForComponents(
        // selector string or array of selectors - the less/shorter - the better
        [
          '.twp',
          '.comp',
        ],
        // every strategy provides the same options (optional) to fine tune the transformation
        {
          // ignore: ["html", ":host", "*"], // when used, these will not be affected by the transformation
          // remove: [":before", ":after"], // this can remove mentioned rules completely
        },
      ),

      // or you can make your own rules isolation strategy - it's basically a function accepting original ruleSelector and returning a transformed one
      // isolationStrategy: ({ ruleSelector }) =>
      //   ruleSelector === '*'
      //     ? '' // returning empty string removes the rule
      //     : ['html', ':host'].includes(ruleSelector)
      //       ? ruleSelector // this way we can keeps the original ruleSelector
      //       : isolateForComponents(".twp")(ruleSelector), // otherwise, transforms it as per strategy (just for the fallback example)

      // it's also possible to filter out some properties
      propsFilter: ({ selectorSet, property, value }) =>
        ![
          // removes the margin reset from a body rule
          selectorSet.has('body') && ['margin'].includes(property),
          // removes the box-sizing: border-box whenever it's found
          property === 'box-sizing' && value === 'border-box',
          // removes the font-family (except inherit) from all the rules
          property === 'font-family' && value !== 'inherit',
        ].some(Boolean), // yep, "some" approach is a bit slower because it will evaluate all array conditions anyway, but it's more readable without || operators
    }),
  ],
};

exports.default = config;
```